# Visual Studio Editor Extension Options Dialog

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mef, visual-studio-extensions

I have a simple Visual Studio extension that is built in a similar manner as the one presented in [this walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee818135.aspx) (using the [IWpfTextViewCreationListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.iwpftextviewcreationlistener.aspx) interface).

The extension uses two colors that I'd like to make configurable.

How can I define an Options Dialog for this extension? (for example, a properties page that would appear in the Tools/Options menu)

I have tried to do this using the [DialogPage Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.dialogpage%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), but apparently it requires a VSPackage and I'm not sure if this approach is compatible with what I'm doing.

Comment: What do you means with VSPackage? Are you using add-ins? Mind that since VS2013 only Vsix extensions will be supported!

Comment: @EDR by VSPackage I mean [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166424.aspx). This is a VS Extension whose code is [up on codeplex](https://netcodemetrics.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest). I was thinking of adding a configuration dialog to make the colors configurable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can make your colors customisable without providing a custom OptionsPage.
You can Export your own colors and they will became configurable from <kbd>Tools</kbd>-<kbd>Options</kbd>-<kbd>Fonts and Colors</kbd>

By your linked example:

```
[Export(typeof(EditorFormatDefinition))]
[Name("EditorFormatDefinition/MyCustomFormatDefinition")]
[UserVisible(true)]
internal class CustomFormatDefinition : EditorFormatDefinition
{
  public CustomFormatDefinition( )
  {
    this.BackgroundColor = Colors.LightPink;
    this.ForegroundColor = Colors.DarkBlue;
    this.DisplayName = "My Cusotum Editor Format";
  }
}

[Export(typeof(EditorFormatDefinition))]
[Name("EditorFormatDefinition/MyCustomFormatDefinition2")]
[UserVisible(true)]
internal class CustomFormatDefinition2 : EditorFormatDefinition
{
  public CustomFormatDefinition2( )
  {
    this.BackgroundColor = Colors.DeepPink;
    this.ForegroundColor = Colors.DarkBlue;
    this.DisplayName = "My Cusotum Editor Format 2";
  }
}

[Export(typeof(IWpfTextViewCreationListener))]
[ContentType("text")]
[TextViewRole(PredefinedTextViewRoles.Document)]
internal class TestViewCreationListener : IWpfTextViewCreationListener
{
  [Import]
  internal IEditorFormatMapService FormatMapService = null;

  public void TextViewCreated( IWpfTextView textView )
  {
    IEditorFormatMap formatMap = FormatMapService.GetEditorFormatMap(textView);

    ResourceDictionary selectedText = formatMap.GetProperties("Selected Text");
    ResourceDictionary inactiveSelectedText = formatMap.GetProperties("Inactive Selected Text");

    ResourceDictionary myCustom = formatMap.GetProperties("EditorFormatDefinition/MyCustomFormatDefinition");
    ResourceDictionary myCustom2 = formatMap.GetProperties("EditorFormatDefinition/MyCustomFormatDefinition2");

    formatMap.BeginBatchUpdate();

    selectedText[EditorFormatDefinition.BackgroundBrushId] = myCustom[EditorFormatDefinition.BackgroundBrushId];
    formatMap.SetProperties("Selected Text", selectedText);

    inactiveSelectedText[EditorFormatDefinition.BackgroundBrushId] = myCustom2[EditorFormatDefinition.BackgroundBrushId];
    formatMap.SetProperties("Inactive Selected Text", myCustom2);

    formatMap.EndBatchUpdate();
  }
}
```

Custom EFDs can provide `SolidColorBrush`es.

If this isn't enought, you can also access to the service provider used by VSPackages. You can make a package for the option page, and communicate with the Editor Extension through the service provider with a custom service.

You can import the service provider like this:

```
[Import]
internal SVsServiceProvider serviceProvider = null;
```

This soulution also doesn't require from you to migrate the original logic, only the creation of an additional package.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I thought some of these links might help you (**NB:** I haven't actually done this myself).

I'd guess you are missing attributes detailed in the MSDN Page:

[MSDN - Walkthrough: Creating an Options Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166195.aspx)

```
[ProvideOptionPage(typeof(OptionPageGrid),
"My Category", "My Grid Page", 0, 0, true)]
```

Some other options are:

[Integrating into Visual Studio Settings](http://www.viva64.com/en/b/0172/)

[Registering Custom Options Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb164654.aspx)

Comment: thanks! I had actually visited these pages when I wanted to implement that feature, but they all revolve around using the DialogPage class, which seemed to not be usable unless I created a VSPackage, which was apparently incompatible with the way that project was built.

Comment: Hmm. Sounds like you would need to migrate the project into the newer style then. Sorry the links weren't more help.

Comment: No problem. I cannot migrate to a newer structure, because it's somebody else's Open Source project and I only thought I would bring a small feature. I cannot afford to mess everything up. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you do decide to go with making a VSPackage (as I believe that's the recommended approach), see [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166195.aspx) and this other [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534804/where-should-a-visual-studio-add-in-store-its-settings/6247183#6247183). I also show how to do this using C# and a WPF User Control for the Options Page [on my blog here](http://blog.danskingdom.com/adding-a-wpf-settings-page-to-the-tools-options-dialog-window-for-your-visual-studio-extension/).