# Reset Visual Studio 2022 Extension to its default settings

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, vs-extensibility

I am the user (not the developer) of a Visual Studio 2022 extension which correctly uses [the built-in WritableSettingsStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534804/where-should-a-visual-studio-add-in-store-its-settings) to store its settings (I verified this by looking at the extension's source code).

After extensively playing around with the extension's settings, I would like to restore it to its original state. Uninstalling and reinstalling didn't help, my modified settings were retained. I also don't want to reset *all* my Visual Studio settings or remove my complete user profile, I just want to reset this one extension.

Hence my question:

**Where does the WritableSettingsStore physically store a Visual Studio Extensions's settings?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's stored in the same place where Visual Studio stores its own settings: **in Visual Studio's private registry hive**.

1. Open the private registry hive with regedit.exe as described in the following question. Note: The correct path for Visual Studio 2022 is `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_71c0f998\privateregistry.bin`.

   - [Access Visual Studio 2017's private registry hive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42916299/87698)
2. The extension's settings are stored in the subkey `Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_71c0f998\NameOfTheExtension`. Remove that key to reset the extension to its default settings.
3. Don't forget to unload the hive as explained in the link in step 1.

Answer (score -1):

You could Reset All Visual Studio Settings to Factory these ways:

1. As suggested in the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/environment-settings?view=vs-2022), using `Import and Export Settings Wizard`.

---

2. Or using `Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022` and typing as advised [here](https://superuser.com/a/1663493)

- `/ResetSettings`: Restores Visual Studio default settings
- `/ResetUserData`: not documented, but it resets the user data to the default values.

```
> devenv.exe /ResetSettings
> devenv.exe /ResetUserData
```

---

**The First One didn't seem to work for me then I tried the second and it did.**

Hope it helps you or others!